# iterating over methods - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, methods, parallel-processing, threadpool

I've created the following threading utility, inside my class `Domain`:

```
def __run_threads(self, targets):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
            future_job = { executor.submit(target): target for target in targets }
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_job):
                try:
                    data = future.result()
                except Exception as exc:
                    self.log.exception(exc)
                else:
                    self.log.info("Data: %s" % data)
```

that's it, I may want to `terminate` or `initiate` a node, which belongs to my class `Domain`. In order to make it as generic was possible, I want to pass a `targets` list, an array of the `target` to be executed:

```
targets = [ node.terminate_instance for node in self.nodes ]
```

or

```
targets = [ node.start_instance for node in new_nodes ]
self.__run_threads(targets)
```

However, when I execute the function I get:

```
test_domain.py", line 19, in test_constructor
    dobj = domain.Domain(name="test_domain", cluster_size=1)
  File "domain.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.__run_threads(om_node.start_instance)
  File "domain.py", line 71, in __run_threads
    future_job = { executor.submit(target): target for target in targets }
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable
```

How can I iterate over a list of methods in Python?

Comment: Just to make sure, you know what you are doing with that leading double underscore right?  If not, you should know that double underscores in python land can mess with the interpreter name mangling.

Comment: Please show the code where you do `self.__run_threads(om_node.start_instance)`

Comment: There's no problem iterating over a list of methods. The problem is `targets` is not a list of methods. Try debugging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback shows you're doing this:

```
self.__run_threads(om_node.start_instance)
```

So you're passing a single method instance to `__run_threads`, rather than a list of instance methods, which is what the method expects (and what you even explicitly stated you want to pass to it). You just need to make the caller to pass a list:

```
self.__run_threads([om_node.start_instance]) # Or a list comprehension that provides multiple instance methods, like in your examples.
```

Comment: Dang! I must be blind!